# Bluetooth HID for mouse project

Tags: bluetooth, library, mouse, hid

I’m working on a project, to create an air mouse for people with repetitive strain injury (since I have it as well). I’m flexible with the hardware required. The plan is to use data from an IMU for movement. I’m currently learning how to work with the sensor.

I have also been researching how to eventually convert the sensor data to mouse movements. I understand that you can do this over Bluetooth (Bluetooth HID, or HID over GATT). However, this is where I reach my limits.

I was hoping to find a library, which can do this for me (similar to the mouse.h library) as it feels like it would take me months learning about the Bluetooth standards to try to implement it myself.

The options I found in my research:

- [Adafruit boards only library so ties you to their ecosystem](https://github.com/cyborg5/BLE52_Mouse_and_Keyboard)
- [mbedOS library, code seems different then the arduino sketches I’ve
  seen so far and is difficult to understand](https://github.com/tcoppex/mbed-ble-hid)
- [esp32 based library,    would need to learn how to use that
  processor and not sure if    supported properly in arduino IDE)](https://github.com/asterics/esp32_mouse_keyboard)
- [Arduinoble.h library, would    you need to create the mouse HID
  profile from the ground up)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLE)

Since many of you are much more experienced than me, I would be grateful for any guidance on how to proceed. Would you show a preference for any of the options above? Or should I be attempting to do things differently, e.g. without a mouse library (but where would I start)?

PS. In case it’s useful, I have basic familiarity with C++ (e.g. I understand classes, pointers, etc.), but I don’t have a programming background. I have done a few simple arduino projects and most of the examples on the official website.

Comment: 100% ESP32. Yes, it's fully supported by the Arduino IDE (and us).

Comment: Hi Majenko, thanks for responding. I saw from a previous reply you'd made a on a different topic that you have significant experience in USB protocols. In the other topic that you responded to, you advise the person not to try to build their own library because it's very difficult. Is the same true for Bluetooth?

Comment: I don't know much about bluetooth. I do know that the ESP32 has good libraries and support / documentation through the ESP-IDF though. What you'd have to do to write your own library depends 100% on the hardware. I'd say ESP32 would be the easiest to write for since all the work is done for you in the ESP-IDF and there will be plenty of Arduino-library-like abstraction layers around.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I appreciate the information.

Comment: just bumping this in hope for some additional insights from the community.

Comment: As a question, it's just overbroad for me to try to tackle with what parts I do know something about.  I didn't mark it that way because I suspect this is not the case for someone else.  I can tell you that HID used in bluetooth and over I2C is related to the HID as it's supported by USB, and that much of the pain of implementing a mouse (or airmouse) will port between them, and different radios/controllers.  This also means that is maybe not as big a problem as you might think if you have to switch between different Bluetooth or USB hardware.  Not compared to the rest of the project anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Comment: The Adafruit library does not tie you to Adafruit boards. Mostly it ties you to the bluetooth chip, that is used there (and if special hardware of the MCU is used, to that MCU family). But that will be the case for nearly every library. I'm not qualified enough to give a proper answer about bluetooth, but I would go for the esp32. It is properly supported in the Arduino IDE (you need to install the esp32 core) and gives you lots of possibilities. Also the programming is not that different from normal Arduinos. Did that transition myself a while ago

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I appreciate you helping out. Useful advice.

Comment: Hopefully we could get some more contributions? I've seen this questions asked a few times on various websites without a good answer. But I appreciate the help nonetheless, don't mean to sound entitled.